# Clustering method when active variable are shares

Tags: clustering

If my data look as follows:

[image: Data[1]]
.

The first column indicates countries, of which I have 40. The last four columns are to be used as active variables in a clustering process, and represent the share of labor used for a particular function (Management, R&D, Marketing & Fabrication). As they are shares they are rather col-linear, and their row totals equal 1. The idea is to cluster these 40 countries based on the 4 last columns. I've done some research on clustering methods but cannot seem to figure out which one would suit this purpose best. Does anyone have a recommendation?

Comment: Since you want to cluster [tag:compositional-data] , you should have a look at methods from that subfield. Applying something like the isometric log-ratio transformation should allow you to apply a normal clustering method on the transformed features.

Comment: Thanks. I have performed the transformation in R but noticed it does not handle zero's well. They show of as -inf or NaN. Is there anyway to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

As they sum to 1, they are essentially histograms or probability distributions.

Hence, you should use a distance measure for distributions, such as X²-Distance, Hellinger distance, Triangular distance (not to be confused with triangle inequality when searching), etc. - anything that measures the divergence of two discrete probability distributions.

Then you can choose from several algorithms, such as Hierarchical clustering, DBSCAN, OPTICS, PAM (k-medoids), ...